# How to draw a vertical line in TradingView pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to use the web based [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/) platform to make my own custom scripts to display various financial market properties. This is possible through its [pine](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Category:Pine_Script) scripting engine/interpreter.

At the moment I'm trying to simply display a vertical line on either the main chart or on an indicator chart. However, it doesn't seem that their scripting engine is supporting vertical lines, except by using the plot's `histogram` or `column` types. Either way, I am not able to get any satisfactory lines.

---

**SOME TESTS**

**(1)** I've had some minor success with using `bgcolor()` like this:

```java
//@version=3
study(title="vbar1", overlay = false)
trange(res, sess) => not na(time(res, sess))
vlinecol = #000000 // black
plot(n, color = na) // check last value from plot but don't display
vline =  (n < 5710) ? na : trange("1", "0700-0701") ? vlinecol : na
bgcolor(vline, transp=0)
```

This results in:

[image]

**(2)** A much better result when using `plot()` with the `style=histogram` argument:

```java
//@version=3
study(title="vbar2", overlay = true) // scale=scale.none only for overlay=true
vlinecol = #000000 // black
cond = barstate.islast
bh = 10*high   // Use 10 x the window max price height for top of vbar (or use 1e20)
bo = -10       // Set offset from last bar
plot(cond ? bh : na, color=vlinecol, linewidth=2, offset=bo, style = histogram, transp=0)
```

with the following result:

[image]

Comment: Hey. Do You know how to draw vertical line on specific day? for ex. plot(timestamp(2018, 02, 13, 12, 00),linewidth=3,color=green, style = histogram ) --- But there is no line on chart :)

Comment: I'm sure you can, but it's not easy to do in pine-script. Look in the documentation and let us know!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone is interested in using the new **v4** *`line.new()`* function:

Note: Adjust *`LineLengthMult`* as desired.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © marketscripters

//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
LineLengthMult = 10
LineLength = atr(100) * LineLengthMult

drawVerticalLine(offset) =>
    line.new(bar_index[offset], low-LineLength, bar_index[offset], high+LineLength, color=color.new(color.yellow, 50), width=3)

if bar_index % 21 == 0
    drawVerticalLine(0)
```

[image: tradingview chart showing vertical lines by marketscripters.com]

EDIT: Answer updated with code that auto-scales the vertical lines.

Comment: Finally some progress!

Comment: In case you are getting multiple lines, when needing just the first, add to your code: `line.delete(myLine[1])`

Answer (score 5):

It is an old post, but this could help others.
You can use this to draw a line:

```
testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear,testStartMonth,testStartDay,0,0)
plot((time==testPeriodStart)?10e20:na,color=black, linewidth=1, style=line)
```

I was not able to plot a dashed line though

Answer (score 3):

Just if it helps someone : Using André's answer above, **static calling drawVerticalLine function multiple times using timestamp**

( you can use Timestamp with GMT / UTC / "America/New_York" ( check documentation for each timezone implementation ) )

[image]

```
//@version=4
study("VerticalLine at specific time", overlay=true)

    // Function drawVerticalLine
drawVerticalLine(targetTime) =>
    line.new(x1=targetTime, y1=low, x2=targetTime, y2=high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#ea5e50, 10), style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    
    // Call Function drawVerticalLine and passing TargetTime
targetTime = timestamp("GMT+3", year, month, dayofmonth, 17, 00, 00)
drawVerticalLine(targetTime)

targetTime1 = timestamp("GMT+3", year, month, dayofmonth, 18, 00, 00)
drawVerticalLine(targetTime1)

targetTime2 = timestamp("GMT+3", year, month, dayofmonth, 20, 00, 00)
drawVerticalLine(targetTime2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dany's answer did not display anything on the chart for me, however setting the style to a histogram did the trick.

```
//@version=3
study("Vertical lines", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)

plot((time == timestamp(2019,01,01,0,0)) ? 10e20 : na, 
      color = red, linewidth = 10, title = "27", style = histogram)

plot((time == timestamp(2019,01,02,0,0)) ? 10e20 : na, 
      color = green, linewidth = 10, title = "28", style = histogram)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bgcolor()` and `color()`, example:

```
vline =  (n < 5710) ? na : trange("1", "0700-0701") ? vlinecol : na
bgcolor(vline ? color(black, 0) : color(white, 100))
```

It is painting a line on every column, but notice that on the `false` case the color has a transparency value of `100`. Nothing renders, except the bars for the `true` case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple indicator do draw a vertical on the market open at 01:00.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical_Line_New_Day" , "#VLND", overlay = true)

isTargetTime = hour(time) == 1 and minute(time) == 0

if isTargetTime
    line.new(bar_index[1], low, bar_index[1], high, color=color.new(color.orange, 1), width=1, style=line.style_dashed, extend=extend.both)
```