# Draw vertical line on specific date

Tags: finance, pine-script

I want to draw vertical line for example on the day specific start.

In manual there is example:

`plot(timestamp(2016, 01, 19, 09, 30),linewidth=3,color=green)`

But this drawing horizontal line instead of vertical.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please link to the "manual" so we can see.

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/

Comment: link the example you are quoting, not the entire manual... anyway, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610638/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-in-tradingview-pine-script). Please recall that SO **is** a programming site, so there are no solutions handed to you without you having tried yourself first. You need to use `style=histogram` and figure out the tick from the date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a vertical line in TradingView pine script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610638/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-in-tradingview-pine-script)

Answer (score -1):

Now in Pinescript v5, you can code :

```
line.new(bar_index, 1, bar_index, 10, extend = extend.both)
```

You will get a vertical line at x=bar_index