# How to draw a vertical line at a certain time in pinescript on Tradingview?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to draw a vertical line, every day at a certain local time (e.g. 08:00 GMT+1).

Since my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610638/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-in-tradingview-pine-script) about vertical lines, pine-script has been updated to include [`vline()`](https://www.tradingview.com/script/EmTkvfCM-vline-Function-for-Pine-Script-v4-0/), however, the issue here is getting the time right. Most servers (for FX) seem to be US based and the Trading view local time settings (shown on bottom left) seem totally independent of what is done in pine-script.

```js
//@version=4
study("Time Adjusted Vertical Line", overlay=true)

vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) => // Verticle Line, 54 lines maximum allowable per indicator
    return = line.new(BarIndex, -1000, BarIndex, 1000, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth)

if(bar_index%10==0.0)
    vline(bar_index, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1) // Variable assignment not required
```

I couldn't get the above to work, but I got this to at least show the lines:

```js
//@version=4
study(title="Time Based Session Bars", shorttitle="NowOpen", overlay=true)
line_height = 2    // We must define a height that reaches far above the highest price level in main chart!

gmt_offs = 2 // GMT + X
nys_offs = 6 // EST (in GMT)

t1 = time(timeframe.period, "0930-0935:23456")
//t1 = time(timeframe.isintraday, "0930-0935:23456")
//t2 = t1 + gmt_offs*60*60*60
t2 = t1 + 2
plot(na(t2) ? 0 : line_height, title='Hello!', color=#101010, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_histogram, transp=50, offset=0, trackprice=false)
```

However, the lines are totally wrong:

[image]

How can I extend the above code, to plot a vertical line, every day at a certain time, and get the correct time placement?

---

Possibly Useful links:

- [Sessions and time functions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html) (The official Documentation)
- [Sessions_and_time_functions](https://github.com/tradingview/pine_script_docs/blob/master/source/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.rst) (The Github Repo Docs)
- [Introducing Pine-script-4](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/introducing-pine-script-4-12626/)

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to *PineCoders-LucF*, I was able to get approximately what I wanted, with the following code:

```js
//@version=4
study("Line at time",overlay=true)

t1 = timestamp("GMT+2", year, month, dayofmonth, 07, 00, 00)
//t2 = timestamp("GMT+2", year, month, dayofmonth, 10, 00, 00)  // Uncomment this to make a range
t2=t1                                                           // Comment out this to use a range
bgcolor( (time >= t1) and (time <= t2) ? color.silver : na, transp = 0)
```

However, there are two issues wit this code.

1. It doesn't use the nice `timeframe.period` functionality that allow you to specify certain days and time intervals in one place.
2. It put the line in the "middle" of a candle so if you're on the 1H chart and want a line at 08.00 it will just place it in the middle. Thus not suitable as an alarm/signal, unless you use a <= 1 minute time frame.

Comment: Guys! Please stop removing the `pine-script-4` tag. *Pinescript-4* is a completely different language and is **not backwards compatible** with *pinescript-3*. What you are doing is equivalent to removing `C#` from a C related question and saying it should just be `C`.

Comment: The first and IMHO the most important reason is that for people who answer the pine-script questions (like Luc, Baris, me and few more) it's inconvenient to keep tracking more tags. Because of that people marking their questions by `v4` tag less probably get answer because no one tracks the tag. So please, don't create excess tags. Especially, taking into accoung that there are no so much questions about pine-script to group them. The second reason is similar - you just confusing new users what tags to choose.

Comment: The third reason is that your example with `C#` and `C` is incorrect: pine-v4 is still pine, it's not "a completely different language". Current version of pine is v4 the other versions are deprecated and aren't supported any more (they still work though, but I don't know how long they will). And the difference between them isn't so big - some variables were just renamed, like `red` become `color.red`, bug in general it's the same language, with the same logic, ideology etc. There are very little of real difference, which broke backward compatibility.

Comment: Compare it with difference between C and C# where one is a low-level language allowing you dirrectly work with memory and another is high-level language with a garbage collector and exeptions handling. Pine-4 is more like if you took C and using macroses changed some words in the language, like `#define Main main`. But because of that you didn't get new language. So pinescript-v4 is still pine-script as Bolgen OS is still Ubuntu. Please, edit your question and remove the tag `pine-script` - by that you'll help to the pine society more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Version 1

One version of the [`timestamp()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_timestamp) function can use a timezone parameter:

```js
//@version=4
study("Line at time", overlay=true)
targetTime = timestamp("GMT+1", year, month, dayofmonth, 08, 00, 00)
bgcolor(targetTime == time ? color.silver : na, transp = 0)

// Debugging: these plots lines in separate window
plot(targetTime, "targetTime", color.orange)
plot(time, "time")
```

Chart is shown with UTC+1 times and indicator is set to "No Scale" not to disrupt price scale:

[image]

#### Version 2

With this version you can choose:

- A from/to hour range
- To show the line on weekdays only
- Between bgcolor or vline mode

```cpp
//@version=4
study("Line at time",overlay=true)
fromHour = input(7)
toHour = input(10)
weekdaysOnly = input(true)
useVline = input(false)
dayIsOk = not weekdaysOnly or (dayofweek != dayofweek.saturday and dayofweek != dayofweek.sunday)
t1 = timestamp("GMT+2", year, month, dayofmonth, fromHour, 00, 00)
t2 = timestamp("GMT+2", year, month, dayofmonth, toHour, 00, 00)
timeIsOk = (time >= t1) and (time <= t2)
bgcolor( not useVline and timeIsOk and dayIsOk ? color.orange : na, transp = 80)
if useVline and timeIsOk and dayIsOk
    line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Also, make sure you're on an hourly chart as only one candle will be shown/highlighted, otherwise you will not see anything. But still missing the feature from the OP code: (a) How to set which days to show and (b) How can we make the lines wider given an hourly range?

Comment: The version 1 code in the answer doesn't only work for the 1 hour TF; it works as long as there is a bar with a starting time equal to the time in the `timestamp()` call, which is what you asked for in the question. Building on your from/to code, added a version 2 with more options.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code I've used:

```
enableTimeLines = input(defval=true, type=input.bool, title="Enable Time Lines")
// Chartlines 1h and 4h
if enableTimeLines
    timeA = 21 // starts at 21:00 hs
    timeB = 21
    for i = 0 to 60
        timeA := timeA - 4 // and from 21hs goes backwards
        targetTimeA = timestamp("GMT-3", year, month, dayofmonth, timeA, 00, 00)
        line.new(x1=targetTimeA, y1=open, x2=targetTimeA, y2=close, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(color.yellow, 20), style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
        timeB := timeB - 1
        if timeB != (21 or 01 or 05 or 09 or 13 or 17)
            targetTimeB = timestamp("GMT-3", year, month, dayofmonth, timeB, 00, 00)
            line.new(x1=targetTimeB, y1=open, x2=targetTimeB, y2=close, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(color.silver, 50), style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
```

It paints silver lines every 1 hour, except every 4 hours, where it paints yellow lines. It goes backwards.

[image]

Keep in mind that there's a limit for the FOR LOOP's time response.