# Draw vertical line at the first bar of the month in tradingview's pine script

Tags: plot, line, draw, pine-script

I'd like to draw a vertical dashed line at every first bar of a month (for daily and weekly charts) or a year (for monthly charts).
How can I do that? I don't know how to get those bar indexes.

***Addition:***
I read in 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828610/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-at-a-certain-time-in-pinescript-on-tradingview)
that "line.new" has a restriction to 54 lines max per indicator. But when using the plot function in histogram style (=plot only single vertical histogram bars), I cannot plot dashed lines... and I prefer a solution with dashed lines...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an adaptation of midtownsk8rguy's code [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/EmTkvfCM-vline-Function-for-Pine-Script-v4-0/):

```
//@version=4
study("Periodic Vline", overlay=true)
p = timeframe.ismonthly ? "12M" : "M"
vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) =>
    return = line.new(BarIndex, low - tr, BarIndex, high + tr, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth)
if change(time(p))
    vline(bar_index, #FF800080, line.style_dashed, 1)
```

Comment: Sry for the late reply, thanks a lot for your help! I'm convinced that does the job. But I just got an error "Could not find function or function reference line.new"... do you have any idea where this comes from?

Comment: Ahh, got it... my script was for version 3 ...changed it to 4 and now it works :-) Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I happened to find a solution to this, but using bgcolor.

```
targetTimeRed = timestamp(year, month, dayofweek.sunday, 00, 00, 00)
bgcolor(targetTimeRed == time ? color.red : na, transp=70, editable=false)
```

You get that at the first day of the month.

[image]

Though I'm not really sure if that's how it should work... But that's what it does.