# How to draw a line on each candlesticks using Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw a line in the middle (based on the calculation) of each candlestick.

```
study(title="Middle-Line", shorttitle="ML", overlay=true)
mLine = hlc3
plot(mLine, color=red, title="ML", style=line)
```

The line will be drawn based on the hlc3 formula calculation.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a similar result by using `plotchar`

[image]

```
plotchar(hl2,char="——",color=#2157f3,location=location.absolute)
```

where `hl2` is the position of the character, you can use different characters if you want.

Answer (score 0):

hm, that's likely going to be pretty tricky. lines usually go across the chart from the center of the candle.

you could try playing with my answer here to draw a very short vertical line:

> [How to draw a vertical line in TradingView pine script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610638/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-in-tradingview-pine-script/62767135#62767135)